# How to use jQuery submit method twice at rails3 ajax form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to transmit data as soon as you enter in the input fields of the Ajax form at Rails3, Second and subsequent times does not work.

documents.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $("#document_form form input").change ->
    $("#btnbtn").submit
```

create.js.erb / update.js.erb

```
$("#document_form").replaceWith(
  "<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "form"))%>");
```

_form.html.haml

```
.container#document_form
  = form_for @document, :remote => true, :html => {class: "form-horizontal"} do |f|
    = f.collection_select(:document_status_id, DocumentStatus.all, :id, :name, {}, {class: "span2"})
    = f.text_field :document_unique_id, :disabled => :disabled, class: "span2"
    = f.fields_for :items do |builder|
      = render "item_fields", :f => builder
    = link_to_add_fields "Add", f, :items
    = f.submit 'Save', class: "btn btn-primary", id: "btnbtn"
```

documents_controller.rb

```
  def update
    @document = Document.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @document.update_attributes(params[:document])
        format.html { render action: :edit }
        format.json { head :no_content }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render action: :edit }
        format.json { render json: @document.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

possibly you are inserting the input fields dynamically, if that is the case use the event delegation like

```
$("#document_form form").delegate("input","change",function(){
    $("#btnbtn").submit();
});
```

this way the change event will be listened for the dynamically added input elements to the DOM

Comment: Thanks. But only one submit event.